# Не добавляются данные в базу после нажатия кнопки / Flask, sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

Коллеги прошу помочь! Есть кнопка на HTML:  Но база не обновляется может ошибка в коде или нужно другой метод использовать

```
 <body>
 <H1>ДОБАВИТЬ ZNACHENIYA</H1>
  <form action="/product" method="post">
     <input type="button" name="product" value="product">

  </form>
 </body>
```

Код на py:

```
 @app.route('/product', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
 def product ():

     if request.method == 'POST':
         with sqlite3.connect('lavaw.db') as connection:
             cursor = connection.cursor()

             cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dannie VALUES ('1', 'Audi', '52000')",[request.form['product']])
             connection.close()

     return render_template('product.html')
```

Comment: приведите ошибку, а так же не забывайте про `commit()` для сохранения внесённых изменений в дб

Comment: Добрый день! Дело в том что когда .py запускаю ошибок нет. Но в страничке НТML когда нажимаю на кнопку product нечего не происходит, то есть данные на BD не изменяются

Comment: после `cursor.execute` вы сразу закрываете соединение не выполняя "сохранение", используйте `commit()`

Comment: Спасибо сделал. но не помогает. Может у себя сделайте).. походу где то есть ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Измените `type` у кнопки на `submit`:

```
 <body>
 <H1>ДОБАВИТЬ ZNACHENIYA</H1>
  <form action="/product" method="post">
     <input type="submit" name="product" value="product">
  </form>
 </body>
```

.py:

```
@app.route('/product', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def product():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        conn = sqlite3.connect('testdb.db')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        db_data = [('1', 'Audi', '52000')]
        cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO table_one VALUES (?, ?, ?)', db_data)
        conn.commit()

    return render_template('test.html')
```

Измените очерёдность доступных методов для маршрута, чтобы не добавлять записи в БД каждый раз при переходе на страницу.

Используйте `conn.commit()` для сохранения внесённых данных.

Comment: СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ! РАБОТАЕТ!